# Submit a pre certificate to Certificate Transparency logs via APIs?

Tags: tls, certificate-authority, openssl, api, certificate-transparency

How would a CA submit a certificate to Certificate Transparency logs? Preferably Google's Pilot or Rocketeer CT.

Would one submit via an API, SDK, library? If submitting should it be a render of a certificate (without log extensions) or the final certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation of Certificate Transparency is specified in [RFC 6962](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6962) and the submission method is specified in sections [4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6962#section-4.1) and [4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6962#section-4.2). A shortened version:

> 4.1. Add Chain to Log
>
> ```
> POST https://<log server>/ct/v1/add-chain
> ```
>
> 4.2. Add PreCertChain to Log
>
> ```
> POST https://<log server>/ct/v1/add-pre-chain
> ```

The format for the POST requests is specified in the beginning of [section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6962#section-4):

> Messages are sent as HTTPS GET or POST requests. Parameters for POSTs
> and all responses are encoded as JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)
> objects [[RFC4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627)].

Comment: Hi Esa. Could you provide an example of how the data would look in JSON format? I know what JSON is, I'm just wondering the specifcation of which fields are needed... is their a CSR or a CRT? - Thanks for your answer.'

Comment: You could first read through the RFC 6962. The section 3 has structures for the messages, and JSON is the input format.

Comment: Did you find the answer to this @Nathanna? Trying to work this out myself.